# Only Allow Certain Programs to Open a Zip

Tags: encryption, operating-system, filesystems, minecraft, php-ziparchive

So I'll be honest right up front. I know what the end product I need is, but I'm not 100% sure how to get there. Please read on so I can fully explain my situation and also some ideas I tried. I was torn between whether I should send this to a gaming form or to here. Considering that this is more "backend" related tho I opted to send it here.

So here's my dilemma. I'm not gonna bother explaining why because it isn't necessary, but essentially, I'm a sys admin for a minecraft server. We work on extremely high quality productions generally including custom coded systems and resourcepacks. One of the biggest problems we have is other individuals coming on to our networks and looking through our resourcepacks (which, if you aren't familiar, resourcepacks are sent from the server to the client as a .zip)
So essentially a individual from, say, a rivaling network comes onto ours and will snoop around our resourcepacks and uncover cool techniques or technologies that we develop. Only for us to later see those technologies implemented elsewhere!

A number of days ago I stumbled across a network which actually have managed to encrypt their resourcepacks so that it's not possible to snoop around them (via extracting them. Remember, these are archive files). When you try to extract or make any other changes to the archive, it will return a 80004005 error which I've come to learn is related to operating system permissions.

**So here's what I'm looking for:**

> How can I encrypt a ResourcePack, or rather, an archive (specifically a .zip) but still have it be readable by Minecraft?

It's that second half which has stumped me.

I've already been able to encrypt a resourcepack myself (using WinZip) which recreated the 80004005 error as well as expected results (like not being able to copy files from inside of the archive for example.) However, obviously because the file is encrypted, there isn't any way for minecraft to read it!
And since the original network's file is encrypted (which I did reach out to them to see if they'll talk to me about how they implemented this feature) there's no way that I know of to reverse engineer the encrypted archive to figure out what method they used.

To reiterate, I have no interest in obtaining the contents of this other network's resourcepack. Rather I'm only interested in figuring out how to be able to encrypt/lock my own network's resourcepacks so that other's can't access it, but Minecraft can.

I'm already well aware that this question is outside of the realm of what we normally see on this website. I'm seriously taking shots in the dark to figure this cool technology out since file encryption and system permissions stuff is not exactly down my alley.
Like I said, 0 confidence on this topic, hopefully I gave enough details for you to help me out!

Even if you may not know much about Minecraft as a game. But have insight into how programs might be able to access an encrypted file while users can't (specific protocols to look into maybe?) I'm hoping I can get at least enough information to piece together the answer I need! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Can you add the ip of the server that made an encrpted resourcepack?

Comment: I don't think it will be possible, you always can create a client sided mod that save the resourcepack

Comment: @Ofek thanks for your thoughts!
https://originrealms.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely impossible. In this case, not only do you have the standard reasons that effective DRM is impossible, but also that Minecraft only knows how to open completely normal .zip files. As for this:

> A number of days ago I stumbled across a network which actually have managed to encrypt their resourcepacks so that it's not possible to snoop around them (via extracting them. Remember, these are archive files). When you try to extract or make any other changes to the archive, it will return a 80004005 error which I've come to learn is related to operating system permissions.

You've misunderstood what's going on here somehow. They didn't encrypt anything. If you post a new question (probably on a sister site and not this one) with the details of exactly how to get that .zip and the steps you followed, someone will be able to explain the real reason why you couldn't extract it at first.

Comment: Appreciate your insight!
I sorta figured that this was the case! I'll def do what I can to look into this more to try and figure out what exactly is going on here!

Comment: At least I can know for sure what is NOT going on here :D